# Is it possible to nest a for loop in a while loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I'd imagine this should be an easy one. I am pretty new as you'll see evidenced in my sloppy code, but I cannot get this for loop to work within the larger while loop. I'm getting a parse error, but I have gone over the code HUNDREDS of times and cannot find a missing semi-colon or comma. Any tip is appreciated.

Thanks!

```
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT `alias`, `max_seats` FROM `rsvp` WHERE `id` = '$id' ");
        $alias = $r['alias'];
        $seats = $r['max_seats'];

        while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo '<h3>Welcome, ' . $alias . '. Please complete your RSVP</h3>';
            echo '<form class="register" method="post">'; 
            echo '<input type="radio" id="responded" name="responded" value="1">Attending (confirm details in the next step)<br />';
            echo '<input type="radio" id="responded" name="responded" value="0"><em><strong>NOT</strong></em> Attending (we\'re sorry you can\'t make it!)<br /><div class="hide" id="hide1">';
            echo '<p>Please select the number of seats you\'d like to confirm (' . $seats . ' seats maximum)</p>';
            echo '<label for="seats">Seats</label>';
            echo '<select name="seats" id="seats">';
            for ($i=1; i=$seats; $i++){
                echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>';
            }   
            echo '</select> <input type="text" placeholder="How many Chicken?"></input><br />';
            echo '<input type="text" placeholder="How many Beef?"></input><br /></div>';
            echo '<input type="reset" value="Clear"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>';
```

Comment: you are missing $ before i in for loop

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I had stared too long to make sense of it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes, you can use nested loop! [Click Me!](http://www.dmxzone.com/go/4937/php-nested-loop-tutorial/)

---

fixed for loop

```
        for ($i=1; $i <= $seats; $i++){
            echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>';
        }
```

the condition `$i = $seats` is not a comparison(it is assignment), will return false only when $seats is zero, for every condition it will return true and also after each iteration the value of `$i` will be set to that of `$seats`

the proper way to compare can be

```
$i != $seats  // not equals
$i == $seats  // equals
$i > $seats  // greater than
$i < $seats  // less than
$i >= $seats  // greater then or equal
$i <= $seats  // less then or equal
```

---

```
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT `alias`, `max_seats` FROM `rsvp` WHERE `id` = '$id' ");
        $alias = $r['alias'];
        $seats = $r['max_seats'];

        while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo '<h3>Welcome, ' . $alias . '. Please complete your RSVP</h3>';
            echo '<form class="register" method="post">'; 
            echo '<input type="radio" id="responded" name="responded" value="1">Attending (confirm details in the next step)<br />';
            echo '<input type="radio" id="responded" name="responded" value="0"><em><strong>NOT</strong></em> Attending (we\'re sorry you can\'t make it!)<br /><div class="hide" id="hide1">';
            echo '<p>Please select the number of seats you\'d like to confirm (' . $seats . ' seats maximum)</p>';
            echo '<label for="seats">Seats</label>';
            echo '<select name="seats" id="seats">';
            for ($i=1; $i <= $seats; $i++){
                echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>';
            }   
            echo '</select> <input type="text" placeholder="How many Chicken?"></input><br />';
            echo '<input type="text" placeholder="How many Beef?"></input><br /></div>';
            echo '<input type="reset" value="Clear"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>';
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

yes.. You can use for loop inside of while loop.
in your code you are missing one $ in for loop. it should be like this only.
you also require to write a condition in for loop.

```
for ($i=1; $i==$seats; $i++){
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Boy do I feel silly.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct pls check once ....................

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `alias`, `max_seats` FROM `rsvp` WHERE `id` = '$id' ");

        while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $alias = $r['alias'];
            $seats = $r['max_seats'];
            echo '<h3>Welcome, ' . $alias . '. Please complete your RSVP</h3>';
            echo '<form class="register" method="post">'; 
            echo '<input type="radio" id="responded" name="responded" value="1">Attending (confirm details in the next step)<br />';
            echo '<input type="radio" id="responded" name="responded" value="0"><em><strong>NOT</strong></em> Attending (we\'re sorry you can\'t make it!)<br /><div class="hide" id="hide1">';
            echo '<p>Please select the number of seats you\'d like to confirm (' . $seats . ' seats maximum)</p>';
            echo '<label for="seats">Seats</label>';
            echo '<select name="seats" id="seats">';
            for ($i=1; $i=$seats; $i++){
                echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>';
            }   
            echo '</select> <input type="text" placeholder="How many Chicken?"></input><br />';
```